# How to assign a method's output to a textbox value without code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How do I assign a method's output to a textbox value without code behind?

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">
    Public TextFromString As String = "test text test text"
    Public TextFromMethod As String = RepeatChar("S", 50) 'SubSonic.Sugar.Web.GenerateLoremIpsum(400, "w")

    Public Function RepeatChar(ByVal Input As String, ByVal Count As Integer)
        Return New String(Input, Count)
    End Function
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <%=TextFromString%>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="<%# TextFromString %>"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <%=TextFromMethod%>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text="<%# TextFromMethod %>"></asp:TextBox>        
    </div>   
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

it was mostly so the designer guys could use it in the aspx page. Seems like a simple thing to push a variable value into a textbox to me.

It's also confusing to me why

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="label1"><%=TextFromString%></asp:Label>
```

and

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server">Hello</asp:TextBox>
```

works but

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"><%=TextFromString%></asp:TextBox>
```

causes a compilation error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of different expression types in .ASPX files. There's:

```
<%= TextFromMethod %>
```

which simply reserves a literal control, and outputs the text at render time.

and then there's:

```
<%# TextFromMethod %>
```

which is a databinding expression, evaluated when the control is DataBound(). There's also expression builders, like:

```
<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database %>
```

but that's not really important here....

So, the `<%= %>` method won't work because it would try to insert a Literal into the .Text property...obviously, not what you want.

The `<%# %>` method doesn't work because the TextBox isn't DataBound, nor are any of it's parents. If your TextBox was in a Repeater or GridView, then this method would work.

So - what to do? Just call `TextBox.DataBind()` at some point. Or, if you have more than 1 control, just call `Page.DataBind()` in your `Page_Load`.

```
Private Function Page_Load(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
   If Not IsPostback Then
      Me.DataBind()
   End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using an HTML control instead of the server control?  Does it also cause a compilation error?

```
<input type="text" id="TextBox4" runat="server" value="<%=TextFromString%>" />
```