# Weird way to write "hello world"

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Changing c++ output without changing the main() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646169/changing-c-output-without-changing-the-main-function)
>   [How to assign a method's output to a textbox value without code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36028/how-to-assign-a-methods-output-to-a-textbox-value-without-code-behind)

How to write hello world without modifying main function?
Thanks

```
int main(){return 0;}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? Do you get an argument string? I assume you'll need to implement some type of buffer overflow to jump functions.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646169/changing-c-output-without-changing-the-main-function

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>

int hello() {
    cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;
}

static int foo = hello();

int main(){return 0;}
```

Comment: @bbaja42-don't forget, only way if you can see the output if you add a system("pause"); in the hello function after the cout statement, but this works

Comment: Or run it in console, since it is in fact a console application. system("pause") is not standard.

Answer (score 11):

Just add this code to a .cpp file somewhere.

```
class Hack {
  Hack() { cout << "Hello World"; }
} hackInstance;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the preprocessor to #define an expansion for return to print hello world, then return.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming there's a creative use of #define preprocessor statements that can make this work.